# mongodb compare two different fields using java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce

this is the data i have inserted.

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("4f97ebb5429c822f0506d9d8"), "direction" : "out", "status" : "complete",  "inputfile" : "data",  "messageid" :"mid_1","previousmessageid" : "previd_1"}
{"_id" : ObjectId("4f97ebb5429c822f0506d9d8"), "direction" : "in", "status" : "complete",  "inputfile" : "data1",  "messageid" :"0","previousmessageid" : "mid_1"}
```

Now i have to query the db and find the records matching the messageid in the first record with direction "in" and previousmessageid with direction "out" in the second record.
I have a huge volume of data.Kindly suggest me a best method fetch the records.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do will be to make two queries:

1. Query for the "first record" according to whatever criteria you want to find that record.
2. Once you have the "first record", you can use its `messageid` and the `direction` "out" to find the second set of records.

Here's an example using the MongoDB shell, though you can convert this fairly trivially to any language:

```
> var firstRecord = db.collection.findOne({direction: "in", /* other criteria */})
> var cursor = db.collection.find({previousmessageid: firstRecord["messageid"], direction: "out"})
```

This will be efficient assuming you have an index to serve the first query, and an index on `{previousmessageid: 1, direction: 1}`.

**EDIT:** Since you are dealing with multiple records with direction "in", you can adjust this technique slightly to work:

```
> var inRecords = db.collection.find({direction: "in", /* other critiera */})
> var messageIds = []
> inRecords.forEach(function (record) { messageIds[messageIds.length] = record.messageid })
> var cursor = db.collection.find({direction: "out", previousmessageid: {$in: messageIds}})
> cursor.sort({previousmessageid: 1})
> /* do something with cursor */
```

You can then process the full set of replies to all the messages in your application.

Comment: Sorry i forget to say in the record inserted i have two more fields from date and to date.For querying the db i get only from and to date from the user.In that case if i get the messageid and then query the db again wil it affect the performance or will it be better if i just get the record in two arrays and then match them.Suggest the best one interms of performance.If there is any better approach please do share it.Thanks in advance

Comment: Based on the from date and to date, do you retrieve one or more than one record with direction "in"?

Comment: More than one record with direction "in" and then i have to compare the messageid field in "in" with previous messageid field in "out"